# Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict:

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

Estoy recibiendo este error en mi nuevo proyecto en Django.
Código de la vista (view.py):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from basic_app.models import productos
from basic_app.forms import products_form
from django import forms

model_name = productos.__name__

def add_products (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = productos(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return redirect('productview_base_products')
    else:
        form = products_form()

    return render(request, 'add_products.html', 
                  {"form":form})
```

Acá el error preciso:

```
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['KF3qMrop5Crow0A2jJ1LnQwjNSDMcUhapFaSayslukSwyW3yiTzvrAhJ1sNPzLxM'], 'code': ['11'], 'name': ['david'], 'price': ['45'], 'note': ['amarillo']}>.
```

El error completo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1772, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'QueryDict'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1776, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['KF3qMrop5Crow0A2jJ1LnQwjNSDMcUhapFaSayslukSwyW3yiTzvrAhJ1sNPzLxM'], 'code': ['11'], 'name': ['david'], 'price': ['45'], 'note': ['amarillo']}>.
[01/Apr/2020 21:24:50]
```

El campo 'Id' debería auto-incrementarse pero no comprendo porque no toma el numero que le corresponde (en este caso el 1), y mas bien recibe un QueryDic

Ya probé volver a ejecutar las migraciones pero es lo mismo

Dejo también el código de la definición del modelo:

```
class productos(models.Model):

    code = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    note = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

Y el código de la ejecución de la migración:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('basic_app', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='productos',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('code', models.IntegerField()),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=30)),
                ('price', models.IntegerField()),
                ('note', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('active', models.BooleanField()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Quedo atento a sus comentario y gracias...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas creando una instancia con los parámetros HTTP POST (un `QueryDic`, una clase tipo diccionario personalizada para manejar parámetros HTTP):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = productos(request.POST)
```

Debes enviar los parámetros HTTP POST, al form, no al modelo:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = products_form(request.POST)
```

Tu vista debería quedar así (por se acaso te olvidaste de validar el formulario):

```
def add_products (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = productos_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # Entra al if si el form es valido.
            form.save()
            return redirect('productview_base_products')
    else:
        form = products_form()

    return render(request, 'add_products.html', 
                  {"form":form})
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias, ese era el problema!!

Comment: Un gusto poder ayudarte!